# How to get the option label for a custom customer variable in an observer in Magento 2

Tags: magento2.3

I am trying to build an observer to catch the form submissions during customer account registration that sends an email copy to our stores address letting us know a customer has registered and what information they filled out. The below code is working, however if the custom variable is of the dropdown type it will return the option ID, and not the value/label located in the eav_attribute_option_value table. Either the label for the front end or admin will work here (store view 1 and 0 respectively) for my purposes.

example: 'account_level' will return as "5" instead of "Wholesale"

How can I get the labels for these options in my observer?

```
...
protected $_customerRepositoryInterface;
...


public function __construct(
...
    \Magento\Customer\Api\CustomerRepositoryInterface $customerRepositoryInterface
) {
...
    $this->_customerRepositoryInterface = $customerRepositoryInterface;
}

public function getCustomer($customerId)
{   
    return $this->_customerRepositoryInterface->getById($customerId);
}

public function execute(\Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer)
{
    
    $customer = $observer->getEvent()->getCustomer();
    $custId = $customer->getId();
    $custInfo = $this->getCustomer($custId);
    $CustData = $custInfo->getCustomAttributes();
    
    $aboutThem = '';
    $accountLevel = '';
    $web = '';
    $volume = '';
    $normalPurchase = '';
    $primeAct = '';
    $primeName = '';
    $primePos = '';
    $primeEmail = '';
    $registerAs = '';
    $years = '';
    
    if (array_key_exists('about_them', $CustData)) {$aboutThem = $CustData['about_them']->getValue();}
    if (array_key_exists('account_level', $CustData)) {$accountLevel = $CustData['account_level']->getValue();}
    if (array_key_exists('company_website', $CustData)) {$web = $CustData['company_website']->getValue();}
    if (array_key_exists('estimated_volume', $CustData)) {$volume = $CustData['estimated_volume']->getValue();}
    if (array_key_exists('normal_purchase', $CustData)) {$normalPurchase = $CustData['normal_purchase']->getValue();}
    if (array_key_exists('primary_activity', $CustData)) {$primeAct = $CustData['primary_activity']->getValue();}
    if (array_key_exists('primary_contact_name', $CustData)) {$primeName = $CustData['primary_contact_name']->getValue();}
    if (array_key_exists('primary_contact_position', $CustData)) {$primePos = $CustData['primary_contact_position']->getValue();}
    if (array_key_exists('primary_contact_email', $CustData)) {$primeEmail = $CustData['primary_contact_email']->getValue();}
    if (array_key_exists('register_as', $CustData)) {$registerAs = $CustData['register_as']->getValue();}
    if (array_key_exists('years_in_business', $CustData)) {$years = $CustData['years_in_business']->getValue();}

...
}
```

Comment: Instead of `getValue();` try `getAttributeText();`

Answer (score 0):

check below code

```
public function __construct(        
        \Magento\Customer\Api\CustomerRepositoryInterface $customerRepositoryInterface
    ) {  
        $this->customerRepositoryInterface = $customerRepositoryInterface;
        parent::__construct($context);
    }

    public function execute()
    {
        $customerId = 1;
        $customer = $this->customerRepositoryInterface->getById($customerId);
        $customerAttributeData = $customer->__toArray();
        $isVendor = $customerAttributeData['custom_attributes']['attribute_name']['value'];

        //OR
        $customer->getCustomAttribute('attribute_name')->getValue();

        //OR
        $customer = $observer->getCustomer();
        $customer->getData('custom_attribute_name');

        echo "<pre>";print_r($customerAttributeData['custom_attributes']);exit;
}
```

Comment: $isVendor returns the ID still, not label. The 2nd also returns the ID. getData is an undefined method and returns nothing but an error so the 3rd options does not work. The array does not contain the labels. example: 'account_level' => Magento\Framework\Api\AttributeValue::__set_state(array( '_data' => array ( 'attribute_code' => 'account_level', 'value' => '16', ), )

Comment: $customerAttributeData['custom_attributes']['attribute_name']['label']; try this one

Comment: the label is not in array.